# Custom ActionBar using Sherlock Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i followed in this way to create a custom ActionBar using Sherlock
Action Bar. my custom layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/brown">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="9"
            android:text="Add Modules"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/addbutton" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Downloaded the sherlock library and added to my project. then my activity class

> public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>
>     View actionbar = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_title_bar, null);
>     getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(actionbar);
>     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
>     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
>     getSupportActionBar().setIcon(
>              new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent))); 
>
>     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
> }
>
>
> @Override
> public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
>     getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main,  menu);
>     return true;
> }
>
>  }
> ```

Problems in my new layout is still black old background visible for some devices. layout not fit with screen.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to remove the default background you can use

```
 getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
```

to remove the three dots, delete the  `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: the option menu button also appears. how to remove this

Comment: try deleting `onCreateOptionsMenu`

Comment: i tried  getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(null); black color dissapered but layout still there

Comment: removed onCreateOptionsMenu and changed android:layout_height="match_parent". now it works